# What does this mean $H(\Omega)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm doing a few questions on functions in the complex plane, and was never given the name for the set of fucntions in $H(\Omega)$. What does this mena? Set of holomorphic functions or harmonic?

Comment: I've seen it as the set of holomorphic functions. To be completely clear, though, in what context did this notation come up?

Comment: It was during learning harmonic functions in Complex Analysis where I first saw the notation.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I mean it in a very specific context, like which book or which theorem?

Comment: @Daminark Ah sorry, it was in my lecturer's homework problems. I can't recall if it was said in a lecture; but the question was along the lines of:  
Suppose that $u$ is a harmonic function in an open set $\Omega$, and define the function $g$ on $\Omega$ by $g(z) = u_x(x,y) - iu_y(x,y)$, where $z=x+iy$. If $f \in H(\Omega)$ and $f' = g$, what can you say about $f$ and $u$?"

Comment: It most likely means holomorphic functions, but there's no way for us to know for sure. It seems like it would be a better idea to ask your lecturer.

Answer (score 1):

Holomorphic functions on $\Omega$ .